# touch device hover to doubletap for sub menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jQuery setting what is the best way to stop default propagation on the first click and show the submenu if the user is on the first click then restore the a link on the second click, or hide the currently displayed submenu if the users clicks on any other part of the page i have tried this with a few variations but none seem to work:

```
$('.nav-bar li:has(ul)').on('click', function () {
    var CheckForClasssub = $('.nav-bar li ul').hasClass('subshow');
    if (CheckForClasssub) {
        $('.subshow').hide('slow').removeClass('subshow');
    } else {
        $('.nav-bar li').on('click', function () {
            var thisflyout = $(this).find('.flyout');
            $(thisflyout).toggle('slow').addClass('subshow');
        });
    }
});
```

this is my current menu structure:

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
    <li>
        <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
        <a href="#" class="flyout"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
</ul>
```

currently clicking on `class="flyout"` toggles the sub menu, but i would love to use the whole link

/****UPDATE*****/

Ok this works fine to display on first click then follow link on second but it doesn't hide if the page is clicked anywhere else...

```
$('.nav-bar li:has(ul)').on('click', function (e) {
    var CheckForClasssub = $('.nav-bar li ul').hasClass('subshow');
    if (CheckForClasssub) {
        $('.subshow').hide('slow').removeClass('subshow');
    } else {
        var thisflyout = $(this).find('.flyout');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(thisflyout).show('slow').addClass('subshow');
    }
});
```

/****UPDATE*****/
To clarify requirments:

user clicks on menu item with both an A link as the parent and a submenu using

```
ul > li + a > ul > li
```

If this is the first click show submenu.

If second click direct through to the relvant a link.

If user has clicked once on menu item 1 showing the submenu  but decided to click on another parent menu item with a submenu  hide submenu 1 show submenu 2.

If user has clicked on menu item 1 and decides to click anywhere else on page that isn't a menu item with a submenu hide the open submenu....

```
    var submenucheck =  $('.nav-bar li ul');
var submenucheckli = $('.nav-bar li a');
showHide = false;
function checkforsubsopen() {
    // body...
    $.each(submenucheck, function(el) {
         /* iterate through array or object */
         if($(this).hasClass('subshow')){
            showHide = true;
         }

    });
    return showHide;
}

    $('.nav-bar li:has(ul)').on('click', function(e) {
        var CheckForClasssub = $('.nav-bar li ul').hasClass('subshow');
        if(CheckForClasssub){

        }
        else{
            var thisflyout = $(this).find('.flyout');
            e.preventDefault();
            $(thisflyout).show('slow').addClass('subshow');
        }
        });
$(document).on('click', function(){
checkforsubsopen();
if(showHide){
    $('.subshow').hide('slow').removeClass('subshow');
}
console.log(showHide);
});
```

Comment: Click > check for a class, if class does not exist, add it and do whatever, if class exist that means it is second click > do second click function

Comment: can you provide an example please?